Euler-Lagrange equation of fractional Laplacian
The following result is in "An extension problem related to the fractional Laplacian" Section 3.2 by Caffarelli-Silvestre. I’m confused how to show it and wish to have some help.
Suppose $u:\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfy:
\begin{equation}\label{energy}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times \{y>0\}}|Du|^2y^a=C\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2||\xi|^{1-a}d\xi.
\end{equation}
For the background, this equality can be derived by the following two equations:
$$u=f\quad\text{on}\;\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\},$$
$$\text{div}(y^a\nabla u)=0\quad\text{in}\;\mathbb{R}^n\times\{y>0\}.$$
Then we have
$$-\lim_{y\to 0}y^au_y(x,y)=C(-\Delta)^{\frac{1-a}{2}}f(x).$$
It is claimed in the paper that we can calulate the Euler-Lagrange equation of the first equation to derive the desired result. I tried but did not succeed.

Not sure what you are asking for: the third displayed equation is the Euler–Lagrange equation for the energy functional given in the first equation.

@MateuszKwaśnicki Yes you are right about this. The third equation should be the E-L equation of the left side of the first one. I'm confused what the E-L equation mentioned in that paper is.
